# openwhisk-composer can't connect to redis server when doing parallel compositions

Tags: node.js, redis, openwhisk

Any body here tried openwhisk-composer composer.parallel()?

my openwhisk action can't seem to connect to the redis-server ive setup,

when i invoke the action with the composer.parallel() it throws error

```
    "logs": [
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0983145Z   stdout: Entering composition[2]",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.09834Z     stdout: barrierId: 374ac5cc-44b1-49e5-8605-5398904d62cc, spawning: 2",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989087Z   stdout: { AbortError: LPUSH can't be processed. The connection is already closed.",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989191Z   stdout:     at handle_offline_command (/node_modules/redis/index.js:851:15)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989227Z   stdout:     at RedisClient.internal_send_command (/node_modules/redis/index.js:885:9)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989261Z   stdout:     at RedisClient.lpush (/node_modules/redis/lib/commands.js:58:25)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989294Z   stdout:     at Promise (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:77:12)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989328Z   stdout:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.098936Z    stdout:     at RedisClient.t.(anonymous function) [as lpushAsync] (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:76:86)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.098939Z    stdout:     at m (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:85:39)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989422Z   stdout:     at Object.parallel (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:130:105)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989483Z   stdout:     at $ (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:149:78)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989534Z   stdout:     at Promise.resolve.then (eval at initializeActionHandler (/nodejsAction/runner.js:56:23), <anonymous>:154:59)",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989568Z   stdout:   command: 'LPUSH',",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989598Z   stdout:   code: 'NR_CLOSED',",
        "2020-12-11T06:49:29.0989631Z   stdout:   args: [ 'composer/fork/374ac5cc-44b1-49e5-8605-5398904d62cc', 42 ] }"
    ],
```

```
const composer = require('openwhisk-composer');

// complexwf.js
module.exports = composer.retain(
    composer.action('step-a', { action: function (params) {
        console.log('log-step-a', params);
        return { value: 'from-step-a' } 
    } }),
    composer.action('step-b', { action: function (params) { 
        console.log('log-step-b', params);
        return { value: 'from-step-b' } 
    } }),
    composer.parallel(
        composer.action('step-c', { action: function (params) { 
            console.log('log-step-c', params);
            return { value: 'from-step-c' } 
        } }),
        composer.action('step-d', { action: function (params) { 
            console.log('log-step-d', params);
            return { value: 'from-step-d' } 
        } }),
    )
);
```

just a little info on my setup, my redis-server runs on docker
have tried connecting to my redis server via the redis explorer in vscode and is working,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to make it work, i changed the redis uri in the input to the container ip not the public ip so the input is like this

```json
{
    "name": "complexwf",
    "params": {
        "$composer": {
            "openwhisk": {
                "ignore_certs": true
            },
            "redis": {
                "uri": "redis://172.17.0.2:6379"
            }
        },   
        "value": "from-input" 
    }
}
```

Comment: i know it's some time ago, but how did you find out the container ip? i'm using the kubernetes cluster provided by Docker for Windows and the container called /k8s_redis_owdev-redis does not have an ip adress (in the response of docker inspect is no ip adress), did you installed redis by your own?